# How to replace a single entry in a column which has comma separated values?

Tags: mysql, sql

One of my table column name  'applications'  has values like '22,333,214,326', I would like to replace the 326 value with null space/blank .Required a function or query in MYSQL which should handle when the 326 is either in as first element /middle element/ last element in the list .(commas should also be taken care)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Consider regular expressions or substring function to find 326 as a substring of a column.

Comment: If you have comma-separated values in your table, something's probably gone very, very wrong.

Comment: got that right berry

Comment: @Elyasin How would you use a regular expression, since MySQL doesn't have a regexp replace function?

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why you shouldn't put comma-separated values in a database column. Normalize your schema.

Comment: @Barmar http://stackoverflow.com/a/986870/1566187

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad